# Erlang Dict. Is it stored in memory or on Disk

Tags: dictionary, erlang

I'm an erlang newbie so I apologize if this question is incredibly dumb. I'm working with `erlang:dict()` to build something that refers to user information as in Kevin Smith's , Erlang in Practice examples.

I'd like to know if `dict` records are stored in memory. Is it something like Ruby's Hash data structure.

Are records actually stored in a `dict` in production systems when they need to be referred to beyond a system restart? I need to store a user Uid, Nickname and a Password for every user who registers on my system but I need the information to be durable, much like how XMPP handles registered users. Should I be using Mnesia in this case?

Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dicts will not survive restarts. You should use mnesia, dets or some other database system of your choice depending on your needs. I guess mnesia is fine for ids, unames and passwords.